# How to place an object without tapping on the screen?

Tags: java, android, arcore

I would be having a screen-coordinate. I need to run a hit test and place an object upon an intersection.

But it returns me the hit test size of 0 every time for vertical wall detection even though I can see the feature points appearing.

Is there a way I can retrieve all the points on the feature plane, and so that I can place the one closest to my co-ordinate. I have searched everywhere and I couldn't find any single piece where I can do that? Is there a good way?

Code:

```
Iterator<Plane> planeIterator =   frame.getUpdatedTrackables(Plane.class).iterator();
while (planeIterator.hasNext()){
    Plane plane =  planeIterator.next();

    if(plane.getTrackingState() == TrackingState.TRACKING){
        Iterator<Anchor> anchors =  frame.getUpdatedAnchors().iterator();

        if(!anchors.hasNext()){
                 //performed hit test here
         }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In their HelloAR sample you can see they gather the points before ever messing with the trigrids. You should find right when to grab them by dumping them to the logcat and watch how they change. When I do that sort of thing, I use the (flat) keyboard to track on in front of the screen, so I can see both at the same time...